# Эффект перелистывания дива jquery

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

Подскажите, как сделать такой эффект исчезновения дива?[как здесь](https://juliadates.com/encounters)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
вот в этом блоке, если на странице нажать клавиши клавиатуры влево,вправо, то идет смена содержимого с анимацией - див поднимается и исчезает

Comment: не понял, какой "такой"?

Comment: нажмите стрелку вправо

Comment: -какую стрелку?

Comment: на клавиатуре должно смениться содержимое дива

Comment: мы так долго с Вами "играть" можем, какого дива?)

Comment: добавил в вопросе описание подробнее

Comment: всё равно ничего не понятно)

Comment: когда нажимаешь на клавишу влево-вправо, то идет смена девушки, и при смене текущий див, как будто улетает вверх влево или вправо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример на скорую руку

```js
let anim = 0;

$('button').on('click', function(){
  if(anim === 0) {
    anim = 1;
    let len = $('.slide').length || 0;
    if(len === 0) return false;
    
    $('.slide').eq(-1).addClass('remove');
      
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('.slide.remove').remove();
      anim = 0;
    }, 600);
  }
});
```

```css
.content {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute; /* или relative */
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.slide {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  transform-origin: 150% bottom;
}

.remove {
  background: yellow;
  animation: Del .6s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes Del {
  99.9% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  100% {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
  <div class="slide">6</div>
</div>

<button>click</button>
```